# Using form setting in WinForm

Tags: c#, serial-port, settings

Hi I want to use applications `Settings` to retrieve some default properties of my WinForm
and I've also included  `using WinForm.Properties` .

But I get this error

> Error 1   'WF_Certificate.Properties.Settings' does not contain a
>   definition for 'BaudRate' and no extension method 'BaudRate' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'WF_Certificate.Properties.Settings' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\saadat\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WF_Certificate\WF_Certificate\Form1.cs  44  41  WF_Certificate

on this line:`cmbBaudRate.Text = settings.BaudRate.ToString();`

note : I declared

```
SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();
```

and

```
Settings settings = Settings.Default;
```

I'm confused . Am I missing something?

Comment: when you double click on the `Settings` in the project what is the property / value is it `string` or is it `BaudRate`

Comment: I clicked the `Settings.setting` in solution explorer and there's a table .The first row is connection string of database and second row is setting . Its type is string but there's no value

Comment: Have you created BaudRate property into your settings?

Comment: No. how do I do that?

Comment: @user2628363 : see here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your settings class name is `Settings1`, then you can use:

```
cmbBaudRate.Text = Settings1.Default.BaudRate;
```

You do not need to do anything else. Make sure you have created the `BaudRate` setting first.